# I am trying to create a table in sandbox and continue to receive this error: Unexpected error Tracking number: c7749408936598037

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery doing the data analytics certificate through google. I am trying to use data from that course to create a table and continue to receive this error. I have tried with multiple data sets. I am uploading as csv files, auto detect schema

Unexpected error

Tracking number: c7749408936598037

Answer (score 0):

if you are using public dataset you can not create table.

You need your own GCP account , try for free trial account if not done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the Google Analytics Certificate as well(using Sandbox for BigQuery), I found that the error pops up and if I close out of the table creation window and refresh the page, the table is included under the dataset.

I'm not sure what is causing this, but I was able to load the csv files that I have needed so far. Hope this works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

As was previously stated above, simply close the "Create Table" window and confirm that's what you want to do, refresh the page in your browser and look under the dataset to find the table you created will actually be there.

Weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to drop the file .csv in google cloud storage.

**Create Table --> Create table from Google Cloud Storage --> Select your source path**

Answer (score 0):

Try to browse project name.
If still got error than upload it in google spreadsheet and than browse project name.
I did the same thing and its working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).