# get unexpected error when trying to create table

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, schema

I try to create a table on a new project but get Unexpected error
Tracking number: c6024433329863479.

I upload a file from a google course and its a csv file format.

I tick the schema and click create table. but I get the unexpected error.

I don't know what to do. I have no idea how to try to fix this.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your browser and check again, the table should be there.

The problem seems to be happening to BigQuery Sandbox users.

I have seen a few people asking about this issue in the past couple days, as shown here:

[Unexpected error Tracking number: c904462681469709](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72291593/18365815)

[I am trying to create a table in sandbox and continue to receive this error: Unexpected error Tracking number: c7749408936598037](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72290112/18365815)

Most have fixed it by waiting a few minutes and refreshing.